# sequilize Referencing column 'partner_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'partnerserviceareas_ibfk_1' are incompatible

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

This is my partner model

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../connection');

const PartnerInfo = sequelize.define(
  'partnerinfo',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    loginSecret: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    gender: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0, // 0:Female 1:male
    },
    dob: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    image: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0, // 0:Value 1:Elite
    },
    joiningDate: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    termination_date: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    line1: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    line2: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    landmark: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    city: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    state: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    country: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    pincode: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = PartnerInfo;

const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../connection');
const PartnerInfo = require('./partnerinfo');
const ServiceArea = require('./servicearea');

const PartnerServiceArea = sequelize.define('partnerservicearea', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  partner_id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: 'partnerinfos',
      key: 'id',
    },
  },
  servicearea_id: {
    type: DataTypes.CHAR,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

PartnerServiceArea.belongsTo(PartnerInfo, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'partner_id',
    allowNull: false,
  },
  targetKey: 'id',
});

PartnerInfo.hasMany(PartnerServiceArea, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'partner_id',
    allowNull: false,
  },
  targetKey: 'id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});

PartnerServiceArea.belongsTo(ServiceArea, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'servicearea_id',
    allowNull: false,
  },
  targetKey: 'id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});

ServiceArea.hasMany(PartnerServiceArea, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'servicearea_id',
    allowNull: false,
  },
  targetKey: 'id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});

module.exports = PartnerServiceArea;
```

These are the two models I am trying to associate and also using default sync.

I need help with the linking and want to use complex query

This is the SQL query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `partnerserviceareas` 
(
     `id` CHAR(36) BINARY NOT NULL, 
     `partner_id` CHAR(36) BINARY NOT NULL, 
     `servicearea_id` CHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, 

     PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
     FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partnerinfos` (`id`) 
             ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
     FOREIGN KEY (`servicearea_id`) REFERENCES `service_areas` (`id`) 
             ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and the error is

> Referencing column 'partner_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'partnerserviceareas_ibfk_1' are incompatible

Comment: Show DDL of `partnerinfos` table as well

Answer (score 0):

Please check "charter set" and "collation" on the both related fields, if data type is "string/char" type.

There is no such problem ("foreign key constraint 'xxx' are incompatible") on integer data type (or at least I have not met such incompatibles).

Sometimes created table has different "charter set/collation" from foreign tables (foreign table created by others, restored from old dump etc).

If create new table (charter/collation to be same as foreign table):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `partnerserviceareas`  (
    ...
)
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

If you have already both tables and would like to change a column:

```
ALTER TABLE `partnerserviceareas` 
CHANGE COLUMN `partner_id` `partner_id` CHAR(36) 
CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' NOT NULL ;
```